# Concatenate string with the number of ocurrence

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm migrating a database from one application to another. In the first one I've two tables: proyectos and presupuestos. A row in 'proyectos' can have one or more rows in 'presupuestos'.
The new application has a field in presupuestos that is made concatenating the code of the proyect with the number of 'presupuesto' of this proyect. That's what I don't know how to do it.

My tables are like:
Proyectos:

```
+--------------+------------------+
| proyectos_id | proyectos_codigo |
+--------------+------------------+
|            1 | E+-00001         |
|            2 | E+-00002         |
|            3 | E+-00003         |
|            4 | E+-00004         |
|            5 | E+-00005         |
+--------------+------------------+
```

Presupuestos:

```
+-----------------+--------------+
| presupuestos_id | proyectos_id |
+-----------------+--------------+
|               1 |            1 |
|               2 |            1 |
|               3 |            1 |
|               4 |            2 |
|               5 |            3 |
|               6 |            3 |
|               7 |            3 |
|               8 |            4 |
|               9 |            4 |
|              10 |            5 |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

I've tried with this query:

```
select presupuestos_id, p.proyectos_id, concat(pr.proyectos_codigo,'_1') from presupuestos p join proyectos pr on p.proyectos_id = pr.proyectos_id
```

Which result is:

```
+-----------------+--------------+----------------------------------+
| presupuestos_id | proyectos_id | concat(pr.proyectos_codigo,'_1') |
+-----------------+--------------+----------------------------------+
|               1 |            1 | E+-00001_1                       |
|               2 |            1 | E+-00001_1                       |
|               3 |            1 | E+-00001_1                       |
|               4 |            2 | E+-00002_1                       |
|               5 |            3 | E+-00003_1                       |
|               6 |            3 | E+-00003_1                       |
|               7 |            3 | E+-00003_1                       |
|               8 |            4 | E+-00004_1                       |
|               9 |            4 | E+-00004_1                       |
|              10 |            5 | E+-00005_1                       |
+-----------------+--------------+----------------------------------+
```

But obviusly, It doesn't what I want. My desired result is:

```
+-----------------+--------------+----------------------------------+
| presupuestos_id | proyectos_id | some code                        |
+-----------------+--------------+----------------------------------+
|               1 |            1 | E+-00001_1                       |
|               2 |            1 | E+-00001_2                       |
|               3 |            1 | E+-00001_3                       |
|               4 |            2 | E+-00002_1                       |
|               5 |            3 | E+-00003_1                       |
|               6 |            3 | E+-00003_2                       |
|               7 |            3 | E+-00003_3                       |
|               8 |            4 | E+-00004_1                       |
|               9 |            4 | E+-00004_2                       |
|              10 |            5 | E+-00005_1                       |
+-----------------+--------------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: I know RandomSeed but I've not written the complete new application and that is a inherit 'feature'

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your scenario, I thought you were building a new application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT presupuestos_id, p.proyectos_id, 
    CONCAT(pr.proyectos_codigo,'_',
        (CASE p.proyectos_id
        WHEN @p_id
        THEN @rownumber := @rownumber + 1
        ELSE @rownumber := 1 AND @p_id := p.proyectos_id END)
    )AS result
FROM presupuestos p 
JOIN proyectos pr ON p.proyectos_id = pr.proyectos_id
JOIN (SELECT @rownumber:=0, @p_id:='') AS t
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want, although the answer by RubahMalam looks better... :

```
SELECT a.presupuestos_id, a.proyectos_id, concat(p.proyectos_codigo,'_', count(*)) as "Some code"
FROM (
    SELECT pr.presupuestos_id, pr.proyectos_id 
    FROM Presupuestos pr JOIN Proyectos p ON pr.proyectos_id = p.proyectos_id
    ) a
JOIN (
    SELECT pr.presupuestos_id, pr.proyectos_id 
    FROM Presupuestos pr JOIN Proyectos p ON pr.proyectos_id = p.proyectos_id
    ) b 
ON a.proyectos_id = b.proyectos_id AND a.presupuestos_id >= b.presupuestos_id
JOIN Proyectos p ON a.proyectos_id = p.proyectos_id
GROUP BY a.proyectos_id, a.presupuestos_id, p.proyectos_codigo
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/569dea/2)