# Distinct order-number sequence for every customer

Tags: mysql

I have table of orders. Each customer (identified by the email field) has his own orders. I need to give a different sequence of order numbers for each customer. Here is example:

```
----------------------------
|      email      | number |
----------------------------
|  test@com.com   |    1   |
----------------------------
| example@com.com |    1   |
----------------------------
|  test@com.com   |    2   |
----------------------------
|  test@com.com   |    3   |
----------------------------
|  client@aaa.com |    1   |
----------------------------
| example@com.com |    2   |
----------------------------
```

Is possible to do that in a simple way with mysql?

Comment: You mean a distinct orderId for each order?

Comment: I guess you looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212402/concatenate-string-with-the-number-of-ocurrence/28213192#28213192

Comment: Yes, like Ullas said. I mean a distinct orderId for each order.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Why do you need a distinct sequence for each customer as opposed to just a unique identifier?

Comment: I think you should not be persisting this value, but instead generate it at QUERY time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want update data in this table after an insert, first of all you need a primary key, a simple auto-increment column does the job.
After that you can try to elaborate various script to fill the number column, but as you can see from other answer, they are not so "simple way".

I suggest to assign the order number in the insert statement, obtaining the order number with this "simpler" query.

```
select coalesce(max(`number`), 0)+1 
from orders 
where email='test1@test.com'
```

If you want do everything in a single insert (better for performance and to avoid concurrency problems)

```
insert into orders (email, `number`, other_field)
select email, coalesce(max(`number`), 0) + 1 as number, 'note...' as other_field
from orders where email = 'test1@test.com';
```

To be more confident about not assign at the same customer two orders with the same number, I strongly suggest to add an unique constraint to the columns `(email,number)`

Answer (score 0):

create a column `order_number`

```
SELECT @i:=1000;
UPDATE yourTable SET order_number = @i:=@i+1;
```

This will keep incrementing the column value in order_number column and will start right after 1000, you can change the value or `even you can even use the primary key as the order number since it is unique all the time`

Answer (score 0):

I think one more need column for this type of out put.

Example

```
+------+------+
|    i |    j |
+------+------+
|    1 |   11 |
|    1 |   12 |
|    1 |   13 |
|    2 |   21 |
|    2 |   22 |
|    2 |   23 |
|    3 |   31 |
|    3 |   32 |
|    3 |   33 |
|    4 |   14 |
+------+------+
```

You can get this result:

```
+------+------+------------+
|    i |    j | row_number |
+------+------+------------+
|    1 |   11 |          1 |
|    1 |   12 |          2 |
|    1 |   13 |          3 |
|    2 |   21 |          1 |
|    2 |   22 |          2 |
|    2 |   23 |          3 |
|    3 |   31 |          1 |
|    3 |   32 |          2 |
|    3 |   33 |          3 |
|    4 |   14 |          1 |
+------+------+------------+
```

By running this query, which doesn't need any variable defined:

```
SELECT a.i, a.j, count(*) as row_number FROM test a
JOIN test b ON a.i = b.i AND a.j >= b.j
GROUP BY a.i, a.j
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can add number using `SELECT` statement without adding any columns in table orders.

try this:

```
SELECT email,
        (CASE email
        WHEN @email
        THEN @rownumber := @rownumber + 1
        ELSE @rownumber := 1 AND @email:= email END) as number
FROM orders 
JOIN (SELECT @rownumber:=0, @email:='') AS t
```